# How to make drop-down triggers work in Haml and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to resubmit the whole page every time a dropdown has been selected, and call a controller action. No Ajax is necessary at this point hence the `form_tag`.

In Haml, how can I attach a JavaScript action to each option so that I call the controller action and pass it the option ID?

```
= form_tag user_path(@user), method: :get do
                  .row
                    .col-sm-6
                      %p.pull-left
                        = 'from'
                    .col-sm-6
                      %select
                        %option Choose one  
                        %option year   onchange: 'javascript: $( this ).trigger("")'
                        %option  month   onchange: 'javascript: $( this ).trigger("")'
                        %option all time  onchange: 'javascript: $( this ).trigger("")'
```

Comment: I'd recommend NOT resubmitting a page each time a dropdown is selected. That results in very annoying reloading behavior for a page, especially if something takes a while to load. Instead, use JavaScript to change only those elements that need to be changed once focus changes from the dropdown to something else.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
%option{ onchange: 'javascript: $( this ).trigger("")' } year
```